# move to element i in scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I have following code to scroll buttons horizontally. How to write javascript function moveToBtn(i) which causes btn index i to become visible at the center of scrollbar.

```
<div id="btnScroller" class="scrolling-wrapper-flexbox">
   <button  *ngFor="let card of cards;let i = index" id="{{'btnq'+i}}" >
        {{i+1}}
    </button>
</div>


.scrolling-wrapper-flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;


  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
   display: none;
 }
}
```

Comment: Use `scrollTo(x, 0)` on the overflowing parent element, where `x` is the desired scroll position computed based on the offset of the button in the parent.

Comment: Also you can use scrollIntoView
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView